# Function WeatherData fails

Tags: curated-data

If I use `WeatherData[]`, only some of my requests work. For example if I use

```
WeatherData[{"Chicago", 3}]
```

I get the correct output:

```
{"C3175", "KCGX", "C8163"}
```

But if I try

```
WeatherData["Chicago", "Temperature"]
```

I get:

```
$Failed
```

Other Collections of Curated Data like `ChemicalData[]` work fine, so I don't think it's a connection problem.

Comment: I know that's not a general problem, but maybe someone experienced a similar behaviour and could fix the problem somehow.

Comment: Works well with me (22.8 C). Retry with a fresh kernel

Comment: I already tried to restart the kernel, but the result is still the same.

Comment: What operating system do you have?

Comment: Windows7 SP1 32bit

Comment: I'd suggest contacting wolfram technical support(support@wolfram.com); it sounds like something isn't working as it should.

Answer (score 1):

This will find the temperature at each of the weather stations:-

```
stations = WeatherData[{"Chicago", 3}]
```

> {"C3175", "KCGX", "C8163"}

```
WeatherData[# , "Temperature"] & /@ stations
```

> {23.3, 14., 2.8}

**P.S.**

```
WeatherData["Chicago", "Temperature"]
```

> 23.

Works ok, but it might be more reliable to use the nearest weather station.

Comment: for me the second part (WeatherData[# , "Temperature"] & /@ stations) doesn't work. The output is {$Failed, $Failed, $Failed}.

Answer (score 1):

Extended comment

In version 10 you get Quantity data

```
$Version
```

> "10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (September 10, 2014)"

```
stations = WeatherData[{"Chicago", 3}]
```

> {"C3175", "KCGX", "C8163"}

```
WeatherData[#, "Coordinates"] & /@ stations
```

> {GeoPosition[{41.834, -87.64}], GeoPosition[{41.859, -87.608}],
>   GeoPosition[{41.905, -87.673}]}

```
tempC = WeatherData[#, "Temperature"] & /@ stations
```

> {Quantity[12.8, "DegreesCelsius"], Quantity[14., "DegreesCelsius"],
>   Quantity[2.8, "DegreesCelsius"]}

```
tempF = UnitConvert[#, "DegreesFahrenheit"] & /@ tempC
```

> {Quantity[55.04, "DegreesFahrenheit"], Quantity[57.2,
>   "DegreesFahrenheit"],   Quantity[37.04, "DegreesFahrenheit"]}

```
WeatherData["Chicago", "Temperature"]
```

> Quantity[12., "DegreesCelsius"]

```
UnitConvert[#, "DegreesFahrenheit"] &[%]
```

> Quantity[53.6, "DegreesFahrenheit"]

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation WeatherData[station,"Temperature"] extracts the "latest" recorded temperature from that station. But it has in its database many stations that are no longer operational. In this case it may return a not available value, however sometimes the last recorded value which may lie years in the past.

i.e. the following extracts 10 stations within Helsinki

```
helsinki = WeatherData[{"EFHF", 10}]
```

giving

{EFHF,D3495,D3161,EFHK,C4473,AP089,C3552,WMO02991,D2819,AS468}

Pulling out the current temperature:

```
WeatherData[#, "Temperature"] & /@ helsinki
```

yields the partially absurd result (today is June 25, 2017!):

$$ 
\{-1.9\text{${}^{\circ}$C},-,-,16.\text{${}^{\circ}$C},-,-,-,13.4\text{${}^{\circ}$C},15.6\text{${}^{\circ}$C},6.7\text{${}^{\circ}$C}\}
$$

Checking the date range of observations at the stations shows that some of the stations stopped observing many years ago:

```
WeatherData[#, "DateRange"] & /@ helsinki
```

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \{2008,3,1,0,20,0\} & \{2017,3,6,15,50,0\} \\
 \{2011,5,4,16,0,0\} & \{2013,12,11,12,36,0\} \\
 \{2011,5,4,16,0,0\} & \{2013,12,11,12,36,0\} \\
 \{1952,1,1,0,0,0\} & \{2017,6,25,14,50,0\} \\
 \{2011,5,4,16,0,0\} & \{2013,12,11,12,36,0\} \\
 \{2011,5,4,16,0,0\} & \{2013,12,11,12,36,0\} \\
 \{2011,5,4,16,0,0\} & \{2013,12,11,12,36,0\} \\
 \{2004,8,3,12,0,0\} & \{2017,6,25,13,50,0\} \\
 \{2009,5,5,15,21,0\} & \{2017,6,25,14,59,0\} \\
 \{2008,3,1,0,15,0\} & \{2015,12,7,11,43,0\} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Obviously, e.g. the absurd value of -1.9°C for the station EFHF was recorded on March 6, 2017 at at 15:50.

This is a bug - WeatherData should return temperatures only if available or provide a warning. If one adds as a third argument to WeatherData a date specification, TimeSeries are returned from those stations that are currently still operational. I'd expect this for "curated" data.